# how to access mysql from server without phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, webserver

I have a web project am walking on, If I to put it on a server in future, how will I be able to access mysql (eg create a new table) without using phpmyadmin.
Am thinking command prompt but how.
Sorry my question might look silly, forgive me am new.

Comment: you can access using command prompt, command is depend on which server for ex window, linux, etc

Linux :
`mysql -u {mysql-user} -p {mysql-password} -h {mysql-server}`
Enter password:

you can view databases using this command
`SHOW databases;`

you can used database using this command
`use databasedname;`

and other command is available.

Comment: If you're using windows set up putty with local port (say 3307) forwarded via a tunnel and then you can connect via MySQL Workbench easily. Otherwise you could just go strait off the command line as mentioned.

Comment: Use mysql workbench

Answer (score 1):

```
# Login with mysql client and password
$ mysql -u username -p

# List all databases in MySQL:
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| my_project         |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+

# Use the database 'my_project' for all later commands
mysql> use my_project;

# List all tables in db 'my_project'
mysql> show tables;

# Show the schema of 'table_name' within 'my_project'
mysql> describe table_name;
```

See also: [MySQL Commands](http://g2pc1.bu.edu/~qzpeng/manual/MySQL%20Commands.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you can use some of the MySQL client. one is the standard Commandline client from mysql. you can start it like this.

```
# mysql -u username -p -h ip-of-your-server
```

or you use a graphical tool like workbench, sequel pro for mac. but there are many more. you can easy find it with google. there you also can configure a connection with the same parameter you are using with the CLI mysql client.

it it possible that you must change the MySQL user to allow logins from a other host as 'localhost'.